# React big Calendar onhover a cell in day view

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Is it possible to change a **colour of a date cell in day view on hover** in React big calendar?

Comment: please provide a codesandbox for this and give us more details on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can apply custom classes to events, using the `eventPropGetter` prop, and use the css `:hover` CSS pseudo selector to change background color of events.

http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-eventPropGetter

```js
const customEventPropGetter = ({event, start, end, isSelected}) => {
  const myClasses = ['my-custom-event']; // add to every event
  if (event.someProp === 'foo') {
    myClasses.push('foo-event'); // conditionally add to some events
  }
  return { className: myClasses, style: {} };
};
```

```
// custom sass
.my-custom-event {
  &.foo-event {
    background-color: red;
    &:hover {
      background-color: maroon;
    }
  }
}
```